Magento 2.4.7 does not work properly after successful installation
I followed the tutorial and successfully installed Magento 2.4.7 twice today, but the website does not work. I'm not sure where I went wrong and how to fix this.
https://www.linuxtuto.com/how-to-install-magento-2-4-7-on-ubuntu-24-04/
I have found the main reason. The default installed Elasticsearch version in this tutorial is 8.15.0. I downgraded the version to Elasticsearch 8.11.0, and the problem was solved.
sudo apt-get remove --purge elasticsearch
sudo rm -rf /etc/elasticsearch/
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch/
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.11.0-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-8.11.0-amd64.deb
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

yaml
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
xpack.security.enabled: false
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch


This page isn’t working right nowwww.123456.com can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500


I Fix the File Permissions.
Like this, https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-500-error/
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chmod u+x bin/Magento

Now, the website shows the following error.

UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/magento//var/log/system.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/magento//var/log/system.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied
The exception occurred while attempting to log: Broken reference: the 'tracking' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist in /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:149
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Handler/Base.php(98): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write()
#1 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Handler/System.php(65): Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base->write()
#2 /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(48): Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\System->write()
#3 /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(399): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle()
#4 /var/www/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(650): Monolog\Logger->addRecord()
#5 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/LoggerProxy.php(140): Monolog\Logger->error()
#6 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(269): Magento\Framework\Logger\LoggerProxy->error()
#7 /var/www/magento/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#8 {main}


Firstly you can enable developer mode php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer and error reporting from un-commenting ini_set('display_errors', 1); from app/bootstrap.php. it will give you more detail abt error

Now, the website shows the following error.

By looking at logs in your first screenshot, I think that you install Magento as root and your permission file issues comes from there.
Then, you have a SQL error in your first screenshot logs indicating that you may have an issue with permissions for the SQL user used by Magento. In that case, your user may not be able to create triggers in DB at Magento install.
Suggestion : Check and fix that last bug and try an install again, but not as root.

As you said, I have successfully installed Magento 2.4.7-p1, but a new problem appeared in my admin backend, here is my screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/3Uek45-zOwTI

Not sure! But I see similar problem with pagebuilder related to requirejs. Magento issued a patch to fix it. I would give it a try : https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/blob/84479c0f3c57a32d7a903e9436f0e192e100e1c2/patches/os/ACSD-52041_2.4.6.patch
